# Не записываются смайлики в бд

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

возникла проблема с сохранением смайликов в бд.
Видно по скриншоту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кодировка таблицы   utf8mb4_general_ci, что может быть причиной?

Comment: А надо использовать кодировку `utf8mb4`.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Так я вроде и использую ее.

Comment: И в клиенте тоже?

Comment: @andreymal Не понял, в клиенте?) Это как?

Comment: @andreymal Клиент - тот  кто записывает данные в базу.